# How to get a list of column names within the same cluster in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, dendrogram

Lets say I have generated the following dendrogram:

```
dm=DataMatrix(heatmap_data,rowscell,text); %Matrix, RowNames, ColumnNames
cg = clustergram(dm,'Standardize','none');
cgAxes =plot(cg);
set(cgAxes, 'Clim', [-1,1])
```

[image]

Now, lets say I want to get the ColumnNames within a cluster, per example the ones I have highlighted with a blue rectangle:
[image]

So, in the example, should get a list:

> AKAP13 BAZ1B Cgord142 BEGAINATRIP ARID4B

Is there any way to get the Column Names items based on the clustering in MATLAB?

thanks